# Problems to fill with Grid Fill

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces, error

I'm relatively new to Blender. I tried a model of a gaming controller I created myself. My goal was to use the grips of a Gamecube controller because I think they fit best in the hand. I put together the whole basic framework from “Curve -> Path” and then converted it to “Mesh”.

My problem now is that I can't fill the whole thing properly.
I hope that you can help me with my problem. :D
Maybe without me having to redo everything, as a lot of time went into it xD
It's only half of the controller as I wanted to simply mirror it later.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JQVSVo7qwwEF0QwHuJV7rz8v5n23IFjX?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe it will be easier if you redo it with a good topology

Comment: hmm okay
How would you approach this and what tools would you use?

Comment: Could you please show some pictures of the controller you're talking about?

Comment: I've already uploaded a picture and the file

Comment: you haven't packed the image in your file so we can't see it, are you trying to reproduce the Gamecube controller as it is or is it different?

Comment: I don't now how to pack the image in my file so i've created a Google Drive link if you want so see it. Sry, I'm really new to this whole thing, hope that's ok

Comment: No I mean do you have a reference image of the kind of controller you want to create? Does it need to look exactly like the Gamecube controller or is it different?

Comment: No, I dont have a reference image, its a combination of a gamecube and a ps5 controller. My aim was to use the handles of the Gamcube controller because I think they fit best in the hand

Comment: So maybe first you should draw a blueprint of the object? It would help to begin the modeling of your object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the picture above, I think it'd be easier if you started over and used regular geometry based poly modeling. Filling faces from curves isn't great because of the wierd geometry and high vertex count.

A game controller is a relatively easy shape to model with basic shapes that you can combine with a Boolean modifier under the wrench shaped modifier tab on the right panel. Use the union function, select the shape you want to combine with the first one and apply by hitting the little arrow.
[image]

Depending on what the model is for, this kind of workflow can get you pretty far.

Comment: ok, thats helpful :D thx
I will start over again and gonna use my first attempt as a reference.